# Swipe to refresh is called out too soon in webview

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I am implementing a program with Nav Drawer which has Toolbar, tablayout, swipe refresh layout & webview

to scroll the webview I am using this repo [NestedWebView](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java)

Everything works fine when the webview is scrolled up the toolbar will hide and when pulled down the toolbar will show . The problem I have now is when i swipe down my webview (toolbar also comes down)the swipeRefreshLayout is also called making the webview reload again. How can I enable the swipe layout to be called only at long pull ? or is there any way I can provide  more control? I really want to keep this layout but the swipe to refresh is too sensitive .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setDistanceToTriggerSync(int distance)
```

pretty simple.